# Is it possible to store data in some kind of model in flutter?

Tags: flutter, model-view-controller, runtime, storage

I want to store data from a form to display it on diffrent other views. I have startet to take the data entered by the user on an input dialog and give them back to the calling screen. but I now want to show this data on diffrent other screens and do not want to juggle the data manually all the time.

I have already found the solution of shared preferences or an data base connection but I am interessted in storage of data at runtime. I would like to use a model in the MVC pattern.

Do you have solutions or examples, which use this kind of pattern?

Comment: You can see different class samples here https://dart.dev/samples#classes, also check the different state management solutions https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro

Comment: you can give this a try https://resocoder.com/flutter-clean-architecture-tdd/ it provides a deep insight of how to implement clean architecture in flutter.

Answer (score 1):

### Provider + ChangeNotifier

Like Sami Haddad said, you should look into state management solutions. I'm still learning a lot about Flutter everyday too, but you have a lot of state management solutions for Flutter. The one in the Flutter docs is the 'Provider + ChangeNotifier' solution:

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro

The main idea is that instead of using the `setState()` method to locally change state/data inside a `StatefulWidget`, you use the ChangeNotifier API from Flutter to manipulate data. You'll make a custom class that extends ChangeNotifier that is solely responsible for holding state (properties), and manipulating state (methods). That class then needs to get instantiated and passed into the widget tree. This is where the Provider package comes in handy. You can provide an instantiation and every widget that is in the widget tree can access the data and methods of your class that holds the state. This way, you can manipulate data, ask for data, etc, from that custom class class in all your other widgets in that subtree.

I would recommend playing a bit with this concept. If you understand it, I would recommend looking into the `flutter_bloc` packages as well. flutter_bloc helps organizing more of a structure that seperates your logic, state management and widgets in an easy manner. Resocoder on Youtube has some very good tutorials on it: https://youtu.be/hTExlt1nJZI

### Flutter_Bloc

Just a quick summary. The main idea behind flutter_bloc is that you have an `Event`. This event could be a enum or a class like:

```
class FetchAllCategories extends CategoryEvent {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
```

This event is used to trigger a state change. You want something to happen, right? This could also be the data from your input fields that you want to store. I used an example from my code. In this case it wants to fetch categories from an API. But first, the state change needs to get triggered. This can be used by the following code where it asks for the CategoryBloc instance from provider. (You still need a way to instantiate and provide this flutter_bloc component in your widget tree. Luckily, the flutter_bloc packages comes with a `BlocProvider` for that!)

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final categoryBloc = BlocProvider.of<CategoryBloc>(context);

  FlatButton(
    onPressed: () {
      categoryBloc.add(FetchAllCategories());
    },
  );
}
```

When the button is pressed, the `FetchAllCategories()` event starts. A little bit of boilerplate from the package itself, but the event goes into the stream and the following function gets called. In this function we check if the event is `FetchAllCategories`. if so,

```
 @override
  Stream<CategoryState> mapEventToState(
    CategoryEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is FetchAllCategories) {
      try {
        // Fetch data from API 
        final List<Category> categories = await categoryRepository.fetchAllCategories();
        // pass the list of categories to the AllCategoriesLoaded class
        yield AllCategoriesLoaded(categories: categories);
      } 
      // catch etc here... 
    }
  }
```

yield is basically like a return, but without 'stopping' the function. So once the event gets called, this class gets yielded towards your UI Widgets.

Remember the AllCategoriesLoaded class with the categories in it? That's the state you want to use inside your UI widgets:

```
class AllCategoriesLoaded extends CategoryState {
  final List<Category> categories;

  AllCategoriesLoaded({@required this.categories}) : assert(categories != null);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
```

Now you can ask for the data in any Widget as long as the Bloc is provided into the widget tree above it. Like so. Remember the AllCategoriesLoaded class had a `List<Category>`:

```
return BlocBuilder<CategoryBloc, CategoryState>(
  builder: (context, state) {
    if (state is AllCategoriesLoaded) {
      return Text(state.categories[0].name);
    }
  },
);
```